# How to save Javascript variable as file on the client PC

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-io

I will post my code in an edit... I'm having trouble submitting my question with the code included.

I maintain a chat program which was already built when I was assigned to it. My job started out just themeing it to make it match the rest of our website. Now management is asking for additional features that are over my head. One such feature is an option the customer to save a copy of the chat log to their computer.

The entire chat conversation is stored in a javascript variable called chatHistoryHTML and a loop causes the chat session on the page to update every 5 seconds by adding new lines of text to the chatHistoryHTML variable and displaying it in the 'history' div for the customer to see.

Right now, I understand how to open a new window to display **only** the chat history and none of the logos, backgrounds, or the text input box. However, I'm unable to pass PHP commands to that new page using my method.

Ideally I would like a solution that would allow the user to click a button and have a save dialog come up that only saves the chat conversation, without opening a new window. I'm opening a new window right now because I'm trying to avoid saving all the other content on the page.

I'm open to suggestions. I know a little Javascript and PHP but know nothing about AJAX

Comment: so you know how to save the file? you just want a confirm box to appear?

Comment: I know how to tell the user to manually save the file... I can't figure out how to use PHP or Javascript to save the file (I doubt Javascript can do it, but I'm sure PHP can).

Comment: While I don't know AJAX, I am willing to use it if someone can provide code for me. (If this requires AJAX)

Comment: php can definitely do it...but im sorry, i dont know how :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primary options:

- Dump the chat log to a new window and call `print()` (isolate the log and make it printable otherwise the user is grabbing all UI elements on the page as well), or
- Use AJAX and send it off to the server which then relays it to an email back to the user.

JavaScript doesn't have the ability to save files locally to the client. However, you have a secondary option:

- Migrate it to Silverlight/Flash to have the additional functionality/features.

Comment: "Use AJAX and send it off to the server which then relays it to an email back to the user." - No need for that. The server can redirect or respond with a mime type that forces the browser to download.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: My understanding is nothing is saving server-side (OP mentioned a local JS variable). However, if it _is_ saved server-side, you're right; you can add something like `<a href="download_transcript.php?conversationId=123455">Download Transcript</a>`

Comment: Perhaps a better way to ask my question would have been: "How can I save the Javascript variable server-side?" Once I can get past that hurdle, I figured I could handle the rest on my own.

Comment: @KennyJohnson POST the content to the server via AJAX.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, I have been trying to figure out HOW to do that for a few days now. I have 0 knowledge of AJAX. The AJAX code currently in the chat program was not written by me.

Comment: @KennyJohnson Then this is a good time to learn. :) You can either use jQuery or the standard browser interface, which is pretty well-documented.

Comment: @VivinPaliath can you point me to the documentation for using the standard browser interface? I am searching but keep coming up with jQuery solutions which don't work (likely because I don't know jQuery and I'm using it wrong). I would rather avoid jQuery, if at all possible.

Comment: @KennyJohnson You can start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: @VivinPaliath This is where I'm at now: http://pastebin.com/57P76TwY. When I click the link, I see an alert box with the HTML code of sample.php. In sample.php I have `$chatHistoryPHP = $_POST['sample'];` and I echo `$chatHistory.PHP` but it does not show up in the alert box. I tried opening sample.php in a new window and it did the same thing - showed sample.php but did not show the variable I tried to POST to it...  

I assume the syntax is messed up somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28844/discussion-between-kenny-johnson-and-vivin-paliath)

Answer (score 10):

All on the client side, you could try:

```
var content, MIME_TYPE, theBlob, a;

// What will actually be put into the file
content = "THE FILE CONTENT";

// The file type
MIME_TYPE = "text/plain";
// Basically, the file itself
theBlob = new Blob([content], {type: MIME_TYPE});

// The anchor element
a = document.createElement("a");
// Set the name of the file that will be downloaded
a.download = "Chat_History.txt";
// Set the contents to be downloaded
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(theBlob);
// Anchor's text
a.textContent = "Download";

// What's displayed as the URL of the anchor (when hovered, copied, etc.)
a.dataset.downloadurl = [MIME_TYPE, a.download, a.href].join(":");

// Add the anchor to the page
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oqskpydg/

This does use features that aren't available in all browsers, but it's a solid option.

---

**References:**

- `Blob` constructor - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob
- `Blob` browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/blobbuilder
- `download` attribute/property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download
- `download` attribute/property browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/download
- `URL.createObjectURL` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL
- `dataset` property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset
- `dataset` property browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: It's also possible to attach blob to existing element. Use `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which is more widely supported than Ian's solution, and it's not dependent on the server side:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,PHVsPjxsaT50aGlzPGxpPmlzPGxpPmE8bGk+Y2hhdCBsb2c8L3VsPgo=">Download chat log</a>
```

You can use `window.btoa` and `window.atob` for base64 handling.

[Demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/d03o7q8zr.html). Show frame source to see source instead of PasteHTML's wrapping.

Comment: @Ian: The file has no extension on my machine. Right click and save as if you want to specify the filename. It's a small price to pay for backwards compatibility. It's 62.22% vs 70.25% market penetration.