# String to txt file in JQuery single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, download, single-page-application

I am developing a single page app with Jquery. The user does some stuff on my app and I save some data in a JSON. Now I want to trasform the JSON in a text file and start the file download. How can I do this using only javascript, since I have no server side?

From what I understand, first step is encoding the JSON into base64:

```
    // Encode the text
    var text = btoa(JSON.stringify(json)));
    //create the file???

    //start the download??
```

Comment: you cannot access the client hard drive client-side with javascript.  You'd need to use a different technology or a service/server-side code.

Comment: @abc123: That's not entirely correct.

Comment: If you want to let the user save it somewhere, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16198097/1282023) out. If you just want to make data accessible to your app, you might want to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: @abc123: of course the user will have to authorize the download in the broswer, I just want pack the string into a file and start a download.

Comment: This is the best news ever! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.location = 'data:Application/text,' + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLCAz/3/)

Comment: Great! :) Can I, somehow, set the file name?